# Comments:list parentId response is broken, please fix it

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

untill a few days ago the api method Comments:list when given parentId returned replies in reverse-time order (as in, last X replies) which is super useful because CommentThreads:list with "replies" part already gives you replies in normal time order. Now, both those methods return replies in time order, which makes no sense, and clearly have broken a lot of clients that relied on this useful data, can Google developer please consider fixing this? There is no point to offer same functionality in 2 places, Comments:list was very useful!

Comment: Actually, `commentThreads.list` with `replies` part only returns up to 5 replies, so it wasn't useful if you wanted to fetch all replies. But you're right about `comments.list` -- Google changed the order of the returned replies from reverse chronological order to ascending order very recently (in the past couple weeks). I was wondering if anyone else noticed this. Seems odd for them to make such a significant change with 0 warning and no mention in the API's Revision History.